# PHP - Difference between object with and without methods in terms of memory usage?

Tags: php, object, memory, model-view-controller

I'm confused about designing model layer in MVC.
After reading this post: [Models in mvc (best practices, PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432249/models-in-mvc-best-practices-php)

As you can see there are two ways to design a model layer in above post.

Imagine you have a `Book` model:

The first way : `Book` is purely an object with properties like `Book` has `id`, `title`...

The second way the `Book` not even has `id` and `title` properties, it also has  `returnPage` , `searchPage` , `allBooks` methods.

What's difference in memory usage if i create 10.000 book objects - all the books will have the same methods comparing the books has only properties?

Should i separate logic method like `returnPage` and `searchPage` in the other class?

Comment: Class methods are stored once in memory; properties are stored for each instance

Comment: @MarkBaker So it means these two ways don't have any difference in memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of the class will store the properties  and the pointers of the methods of the function which will store once of the class. When call method function form the instance, it will jump to the function stored with the method pointer, then execute the function. When the function execute, the function caller will use the call stack to store the temp value. Each caller will have their own call stack, so there will be no conflicts between instances when call the class functions.

Comment: Don't get your point, please answer directly to the question, what's the difference and does it impact to the memory usage of these two ways of designing models?

Comment: ok,make IT EASY, book have to store property and pointer to the function. so they Will  take different amount of memory